# Hidden URL in APK

Tags: java, android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I am trying to find the code in an APK that makes a request to a server. Using fiddler I know the full URL.

So I used apktool and got the samali code and used dex to get the java code. I have searched both for the domain name and even a url parameter name (think searching for "userid" but get no results.

How is this possible? And yes I have looked in the resource files as well. Not there. I have tried googling at lot but all I seem to find are things about obfuscation which doesn't really apply because the URL couldn't be obfuscated, besides the code isn't obfuscated.

Comment: Maybe it's located in resource folder under `res`, possibly in `res/values/string.xml`, `grep -r` on the whole `res` folder

Comment: @BertrandMartel looked there. They also use string to byte array encoding/decoding so I used regex to find any file that had just three of the letters in ascii in the file not even in a specific order and nothing.

Comment: That's easy accomplishable: there can be in-code obfuscation to protect from grepping over the decompiled code, say something like a character array optionally transformed and converted to string in runtime. Try to search for the code that makes the requests and try to traverse the referencing code.

Comment: have you succeed to find those urls?